# Getting NullPointerException when browsing a page

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.6

When browsing non core pages using DXA 1.6 - Tridion 2013 SP1 I start getting a null pointer exception. Checking the source code it seems the error happens here:

```
entity = (EntityModel)semanticMapper.createEntity(entityClass, semanticSchema.getSemanticFields(), new SemanticFieldDataProviderImpl(new com.sdl.webapp.tridion.SemanticFieldDataProviderImpl.ComponentEntity(component), fieldConverterRegistry, builder));
```

Bellow the stack trace

```
01:13:54.663 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] ERROR c.s.w.c.controller.BaseController - Exception while processing request for: http://localhost:8080/dxa-web/caas
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.EntityBuilderImpl.createEntity(EntityBuilderImpl.java:301) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.EntityBuilderImpl.createEntity(EntityBuilderImpl.java:265) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl$1.apply(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:63) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl$1.apply(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:60) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createEntityModelInternal(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:91) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:60) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.PageBuilderImpl$DD4TRegionBuilderCallback.buildEntity(PageBuilderImpl.java:623) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.DefaultRegionBuilder.buildRegions(DefaultRegionBuilder.java:46) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.PageBuilderImpl.createPage(PageBuilderImpl.java:257) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createPageModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:53) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultContentProvider$1.tryFindPage(AbstractDefaultContentProvider.java:232) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultContentProvider$1.tryFindPage(AbstractDefaultContentProvider.java:212) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.util.LocalizationUtils.findPageByPath(LocalizationUtils.java:162) ~[dxa-common-api-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultContentProvider.getPageModel(AbstractDefaultContentProvider.java:212) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
```

Comment: Obviously there is an exception happening in the model mapping, would be beneficial if you can at least narrow it down to a single entity model on a Page and **edit** your question and add the source of the model and some information about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to publish the 'Publish Settings' page. Then also access http://localhost:8080/admin/refresh to make sure the new internal .json files are up to date on the filesystem.